# For loop forced to start with a modifier

Tags: java, for-loop

I've recently run into a issue with for loops. My method looks like this:

```
public static void countdown(int i) {
    System.out.println("Counting down from 10");
    for (i; i >= 1; i--){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

This however returns a syntax error telling me to add a modifier "++" to the initializing value of the for loop. However i don't want that. Is there anyway to avoid doing that?

Comment: You lack closing `}` in your method? Or just typo?

Comment: Remove the `i`. To read `for(;i>=1;i--)`

Comment: Why don't you use a `while` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialization expression is executed once, as the loop begins, but you are not doing anything with i. Therefore just remove it from the loop like so:

```
for (; i >= 1; i--){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: You could also avoid about 50ms of confusion for future maintainers by doing something like `for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--)`, although this is redundant.

Comment: TY, that exactly what i wanted to do. I knew i could reassign i to a new value which i declared in the initialization of the for loop. However just like Duncan said i felt that was redundant since i already had declared a working variable i wanted to use. I'm quite new the programming so had no idea i could leave the initalization field empty like that :D

Comment: No worries and just a little extra knowledge for you then, all three sections are actually optional in a for loop! An infinite loop can be created with: `for ( ; ; ) { //more code here }`

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign starting value of `i`

```
for (i; i >= 1; i--) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

You can use

```
for (i=10; i >= 1; i--) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

or you can just remove `i`

```
 for (; i >= 1; i--) { // i is already initialized
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

You can introduce a new local variable too

```
for (int k=i;k >= 1; k--) {
   System.out.println(k);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this solution will help you understand your problem.

```
class Hello {

 public static void countdown(int j) {
    System.out.println("Counting down from 10");
       for (int i= j; i >= 1; i--){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    countdown(5);
    }
    }

Output:

5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of a for-loop is the following:

```
for(INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; INCREMENT/DECREMENT)
```

Since your i is already initialized, your loop should look like this, since you skip the Initialization in the loop

```
for (; i >= 1; i--)
```

I would rather write the loop as follows, since it's easier to read:

```
public static void countdown(int start) {
System.out.println("Counting down from " + start);
for (int i = start; i >= 1; i--){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```